# AWS load-balanced IIS site returns internal IP address in 301/Redirect response

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis-7.5, load-balancing

I've got a load balanced IIS web application in AWS. Most redirects return the correct location, but when a Http/1.0 request is made with no `host` header, the `Location` header in the response appears to be the internal IP address of the load balancer.

This was flagged up in a penetration test as a minor issue.

Is it possible to configure IIS, or the load balancer to return the host name here instead? Or is it not an issue worth fixing?

I've already added a `system.webServer/serverRuntime/alternativeHostname` key to the configuration of the two IIS servers, but this has not helped.

Comment: Which load balancer (NLB, ALB or CLB)?

Comment: We're using CLB